# How can I properly list items in xaringan slide without misaligned dots?

Tags: xaringan

I often encounter the misaligned dots whenever I list the items in xaringan slides for some reason. I think I ensure that there's no extra or unnecessary space between the codes or items. I just want to know what kind of mistakes I usually make in this case. FYI, there is only a single space between `# Consistency` and `####` and `####` is for larger fontsize. I know `-` is a simple way to list but this size is sometimes smaller for my need.

```
---
# Consistency

#### </li> How does an estimator perform? <li>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this `#### </li> How does an estimator perform? <li>` instead of `-  How does an estimator perform? ` ???

Comment: `####` is for fontsize and sometimes `-` is too small for the subtitle.

Comment: you can increase the fontsize using css easily.

Comment: thanks, since the size doesn't seem much different, maybe I can stick to `-`.